# How to divide text in EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need input text(digits) in EditText and i want to divide group of digits by 4 digits.

if i input `000000000000` i want see something like this `0000 0000 0000` .

My EditText:

```
        @NotEmpty
        @InjectView(R.id.paymentCode)
        EditText paymentCodeField;
...

    paymentCodeField.setOnTouchListener(eventHandler);
...
```

I think it need listener but i don't know how do it.

I tried below code

```
paymentCodeField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

but i don't know how to use it.

Comment: make 4 edit text with max length 4 character and use addTextChangedListener to jump to next edit text field

Comment: see this http://www.codeitive.com/0HHgPVqjPj/custom-format-edit-text-input-android-to-accept-credit-card-number.html

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10252782/1479511

Comment: the first one was my own implementation idea, second one i find it for you. Both will work...

Comment: http://horribile.blogspot.co.nz/2011/12/using-mask-with-edittext.html

Answer (score 2):

A way to get it is creating a mask, but android don't help us with that purpose.

You can implement your own mask, or you can use a library.

https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText/tree/master/MaskedEditText

```
<br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    mask:mask="#### #### ####"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Add a `count` global variable to count the number of input `char`.

**2.** Update `count` inside `onTextChanged()` and add checking inside `afterTextChanged()`.

**3.** If count equal `4`, then add `space` to current editable `text` and set it to `EditText` and also change the `cursor` position to last using `setSelection()` method.

**4.** Finally, rest `count` value for next inputs.

**Here is the working code:**

```
    int count = 0;

    ................
    ....................

    paymentCodeField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            count++;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            if (count == 4) {
                String str = editable.toString();
                str = str + " ";

                editText.setText(str);

                // Required to move cursor position after space
                editText.setSelection(str.length());

                count = 0;
            }
        }
    });
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

Try this one : This is for phone number

```
_edtphonenumber=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_phonenumber);

    _edtphonenumber.setTypeface(trajan_pro_regular);
    _edtphonenumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        private boolean mFormatting; // this is a flag which prevents the  stack overflow.
        private int mAfter;

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // nothing to do here.. 
        }

        //called before the text is changed...
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            //nothing to do here...
            mAfter  =   after; // flag to detect backspace..

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // Make sure to ignore calls to afterTextChanged caused by the work done below
            if (!mFormatting) {
                mFormatting = true;
                // using US formatting...
                if(mAfter!=0) // in case back space ain't clicked...
                    PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(s,PhoneNumberUtils.getFormatTypeForLocale(Locale.US));                             
                mFormatting = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write code into beforeTextChanged

```
paymentCodeField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
if (charSequence.length() % 4 == 0) paymentCodeField.setText(charSequence.toString() + " ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

You can customize your input into Edit Text, it will help you !!

Answer (score 0):

After text change replace all spaces and insert space in request position

```
paymentCodeField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            s.toString().replace(" ","");

            if(s.toString().length()>4 && s.toString().charAt(4)!=' ')
                s.insert(4," ");

            if(s.toString().length()>9 && s.toString().charAt(9)!=' ')
                s.insert(9," ");
        }
    });
```