# Giving space to text inputed into editText

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an edit text in an application that receives inputs of numbers. How can I change the space between the numbers so they can be far apart?

Also is it possible to have an input the looks like: *1174 4453 3456 3456* where the space between the numbers come after a specific number of inputs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790102/format-credit-card-in-edit-text-in-android

Comment: Is this edit text for a credit card?
[Someone answer that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36968886/11322051)

Comment: Not a credit card but something like it

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:letterSpacing="0.50"`

Comment: This will add space between each character rather than in between every 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextWatcher:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    private static final char spc = ' ';

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        if (s.length() > 0 && (s.length() % 5) == 0) {
            final char c = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
            if (spc == c) {
                s.delete(s.length() - 1, s.length());
            }
        }

        if (s.length() > 0 && (s.length() % 5) == 0) {
            char c = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
            if (Character.isDigit(c) && TextUtils.split(s.toString(), String.valueOf(spc)).length <= 3) {
                s.insert(s.length() - 1, String.valueOf(spc));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

For space betwin character you can use
 `android:letterSpacing` 
In xml file